# How does strace interpret syscall arguments?

Tags: c, strace

I know it uses `ptrace` for implementation,

and it can get arguments in registers,

but they're numbers only,

how does strace convert them into literal information?

Is it just hard code for every syscall?

Comment: Probably, or possibly a lookup table for different sets of arguments (because `read()` and `write()` have the same args).

Comment: read() and write() don't have quite the same args - it doesn't print the value of read()'s buffer until after return.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes, its hardcoded.  If you look at [the sourcecode](https://github.com/strace/strace) ([detail](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/linux/x32/syscallent.h)), you can see big tables of system calls and big switch statements that know how to decode all their various arguments and return values for multiple different OSes and CPUs

Comment: Uh, maybe I'm blind but can you point to e.g. the table of syscall arguments for the open syscall? Thanks!